# Pytest/Fabric not using SSH agent when debugging in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, pytest, fabric, ssh-agent

I am writing some infrastructure tests using pytest and fabric. Generally this is working. I run a test from the command line that executes a fabric task on a remote server and asserts something about the result of that task. The task is executed using my running SSH agent.

However, when I try to debug my tests in PyCharm the fabric tasks fail with the following exception

```
Fatal error: Needed to prompt for a connection or sudo password, but input would be ambiguous in parallel mode
```

This difference in behavior leads me to believe something isn't configured properly in my debug configuration. I have made sure that environment variables in debug config includes the SSH agent PID.

Comment: Please share how you have set pycharm to debug this script

Comment: @TalhaJunaid I switched to using the poetry plugin for PyCharm and that seems to have fixed it